# Deterime neighbours list in parallel

Tags: r, parallel-processing, knn

I have a large dataset containing n polygons and I would like to determine a neighbour list of the k closest polygons with the `knn2nb` library. To perform a sensitivity test, I would like my k-value to take all the values between 1:n. This is fairly easy in R with `lapply`:

```
#Create neighbours list    
lapply(1:n, function(k) knn2nb(knearneigh(coords, k=k), row.names=coordsID)
```

Still, because my dataset is large, the process is very slow, and I was thinking to use `parLapply` that comes with the R package `parallel`. This is what I did:

```
# Calculate the number of cores
no_cores <- detectCores() - 1

# Initiate cluster
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)

#Create neighbours list
parLapply(cl, 1:n, function(k) knn2nb(knearneigh(coords, k=k), row.names=coordsID))
```

Still, I get this error:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  7 nodes produced errors; first error: impossible to find the function "knn2nb"
```

I am fairly new to lapply and definitely a novice with parallel computing. The library `knn2nb` is of course installed and loaded.

Could anyone tell me what did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you not missing `library(spdep)`, i.e.: `spdep::knn2nb`?

Comment: Hi, no, everything is installed and loaded. It runs smoothly with laplly but not with parLapply. I just now realized what I was missing. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On-line (e.g., [here](https://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2012/08/19/parallelization-speed-up-functions-in-a-package/)), I could find an answer to my problem. One need to set the `clusterExport`. See below:

```
# Calculate the number of cores
no_cores <- detectCores() - 1

# Initiate cluster
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)

clusterExport(cl, c("knn2nb", "knearneigh","coords", "coordsID"), envir=environment()) 

parLapply(cl, 1:n, function(k) knn2nb(knearneigh(coords, k=k), row.names=coordsID))
```

I hope that this answer can help.